# Regex: Robust way to handle string numbers

Tags: php, regex, pcre

### Edit:

I don't know if that's even possible to recreate in regex and @Paul Crovella pointed out that this may not be suitable to solve the problem, but just for fun I want to do something like this:

1. Start from right to left. Match first character which is either a dot or a comma `/(?<seperator>[.,])\d+$/`
2. Reset the pointer and capture every digit until decimal character recursively  (without capturing anything but digits) `/(?<number>(?:\d+[^\1])+\d+)/`
3. Get decimal places `/(?<decimal)\d+(?<=\1)/`

*Additional rules*

- If there is only one [.,] it is the decimal point
- If there is only one of these [.,\h] it is the hunderds/thousands seperator
- If the first captures non-digit character is found multiple times it is the hunderds/thousands seperator
- The hunderds/thousands is always the same so it should be possible to write a recursive lookahead which always stops at the character and "fills" a group with digits

### Original:

I'm building a class in PHP which converts between units. I've got everything working so far and now I'm trying to create a robust way to convert the input strings into floats.

Here are some test strings which my class should handle:

```
123456789
1234567.89
1234567,89
1,234,567.89
1.234.567,89
123 456 789
1 234 567.89
1 234 567,89
```

To make this feasible I have to make some assumptions:

- The string could be a whole number
- The string could have decimal places seperated by `[.,]`
- The string could be grouped (by hundreds/thousands) seperated by `[.,\h]`
- The seperators are consistent and different from each other

I think the best "do it once, do it right" way is to solve this with a regex.

First you have to gather the first seperator

```
/^\d+(?<s>[.,\h])/
```

Then you have to reset the pointer and backreference the symbol

```
/^(?<b>(\d+)${s}(\d+))/
```

I don't want the seperator in the actual group but I don't know how to achive that.

The next step is to match `[^${s}](?<d>\d+)` for the decimals group.

Lastly add the two numbers together

```
return (float) $matches['b'] . '.' . $matches['d'];
```

I came up with a few solutions but none of them worked quite right. I'm hoping for some input from the community. Please include a description of what each block is doing so I can learn from you.

Best regards.

P.S. Bonus points for adding the possibility to parse these as well

```
123^2
123^-2
123 ^2
123^ 2
123²
123³
```

The first four I can do but for the last two I'm looking for a method of substituting superscript to numbers (I can do that with `str_replace` too but I know that this should be possible in the regex itself).

Comment: So how do you want to resolve ambiguous strings such as `123,456`, which can be interpreted as either `123456.0` or `123.456`? Or do all input strings have no more than 2 decimal places?

Comment: Assuming decimals are always 2 decimal places I think this would work. https://3v4l.org/nclkR

Comment: Thats a good question! I think the safest bet, without passing additional function arguments, is to just assume that if there is only one dot or comma present, that it should be the decimal point.

Comment: @Paul Crovella But using NumberFormatter would require passing even more arguments to my class. And if I pass, let's say data from a parsed website, I may or may not know what particular number format is being used.

Comment: @Paul Is this question Too Broad to answer succinctly?

Comment: @Paul Crovella Valid point. How about this approach: Pass arguments if I know what type of string I'm dealing with and parse it with NumberFormatter. If I have no idea, fuzzy match it with a regex.

Comment: ...plus the "bonus" challenge at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`^(?|(\d{1,3}(?=([.,\h])?)(?:\2\d{3})*)(?:(?!\2)[.,](\d*))|(\d+)()(?:[.,](\d*))?|()()[.,](\d+))$`

https://regex101.com/r/ZMJEmb/1

The *whole number* is in group 1.
The *fractional number* is in group 3.

Globally repalce `\D` with nothing  on group 1 after match, to strip out thousands separators.

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?|                           # Branch Reset

                                    # Form D,DDD,DDD.dd
      (                             # (1 start), Whole number
           \d{1,3} 
           (?=
                ( [.,\h] )?                   # (2), Thousands seperator
           )
           (?:
                \2 
                \d{3} 
           )*
      )                             # (1 end)
      (?:
           (?! \2 )
           [.,]                          # This form requires at least a fractional separator
           ( \d* )                       # (3), Fractional number, optional
      )
   |  

      ( \d+ )                       # (1), Whole number
      ( )                           # (2), Thousands seperator N/A
      (?:
           [.,] 
           ( \d* )                       # (3), Fractional number, optional
      )?
   |                              # or, Form .dd
      ( )                           # (1), Whole number N/A
      ( )                           # (2), Thousands seperator N/A
      [.,] 
      ( \d+ )                       # (3), Fractional number
 )
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: Hey man thank you for your effort. Is there a way to just get the number without the seprators? Maybe with a recursive function? Replacing `\D`is an extra step I'd like to avoid.

Comment: This regexp doesn't seem to match "1,234,567" Is that supposed to be matched? @user3462116

Comment: @user3462116 - It can be done in the Dot-net engine using Capture Collections. Not in any other engines though. As far as the extra step with the `\D`, the regex here has 12 steps in a single regex, I don't think it's gonna hurt.

Comment: @Julio - Sure, that can be accounted for. But if you look at the line commented `# This form requires at least a fractional separator` it was put there to distinguish thousands separator `123,456` from fractional  separator `123,456`. All things are possible though...

Comment: @Julio `'1,234,567'` should be interpreted as `123456789`. I'll try to come up with a new solution based off of the input I've received so far and if you guys are interessted I will post it here. Thanks for you work @sln

Comment: I've tried my best (I really hate regex). Can you tell me why `^(?<n>(?:.+(?=\g<+1>))*)(?<d>[.,\h]?)(?<f>\d*)$` doesn't work and help me improve it?

Comment: @user3462116 - That regex is the exact equivalent  of `^.+$`. I don't know what you're trying to do, so I don't know how to help. I can tell you _why_ it is equivalent, maybe that would help. `(?<n>(?:.+(?=(?+1)))*)` contains the core `.+` along with an assertion that calls `(?<d>[.,\h]?)`, <- but this is optional, so it always matches, and the assertion always returns true.

Comment: Start of string -> Group 1 (match anything until character found in group 2) -> Group 2 (match character it there is a character) -> Group 3 (match fraction if any) -> End of string
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat '333.333' as decimal separator, use this:

```
^(\d{0,3}(?=([.,](?!\d+$)| |))(?:\2\d{3})*)(?:[,.](\d*))?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/TOrxA0/4/

```
^
  (
    \d{0,3} # Match up to 3 digits so we can...
    (?=([.,](?!\d+$)| |)) # get first separator. Will be used down here:
    (?:\2\d{3})* # get group of 3 digits with previous separator, greedy
  ) # first block
  (?:
      [,.](\d*) # decimal separator + digits
  )? # last block
$
```

If you want to treat '333.333' as a number separator use:

```
^(\d{0,3}(?=([ .,]|))(?:\2\d{3})*)(?:[,.](\d*))?$
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/BsaARo/3/

```
^
 (
  \d{0,3} # Match up to 3 digits so we can...
  (?=([ .,]|)) # get first separator. Will be used down here:
    (?!\d+$)   # Optional: is just one separator is present, it will be a decimal point
  (?:\2\d{3})* # get group of 3 digits with previous separator, greedy
 ) # First block
 (?:
   [,.](\d*) # decimal separator + digits
 )? # Last block
$
```

Edit: Replaced some \d\d\d by \d{3}

Comment: Hey man thank you for your effort. Is there a way to just get the number without the seprators? Maybe with a recursive function? Replacing `\D`is an extra step I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot because of this: `(\2\d{3})*` that block repeats (separator + 3 numbers) several times. If I want to capture all those numbers, the capturing group must be outside the star and that will fetch the separator.

While regular expressions are powertful, It is not a bad idea to use several steps if that avoids complicating the regexes too much. It helps with maintenance.

Comment: @user3462116 On may answer, the first regexp, will match 1,234,567 as a whole number and 123,456 as a fractional number as you seem to require. The second regexp will match 1,234,567 and 123,456 as whole numbers. In either case you may need to remove \D on the first part.

Comment: Your first regex seems to do exactly what I want. Thank you for that! Just a few ideas:

 - `(?=([.,](?!\d+$)| |))` matches either `[.,]`, `[ ]` (would prefer `[\h]`) or either nothing. Why not just include the space in the first character list and make add a quantifier so you don't have to match against nothing?
 - `\d+$` feels weird. Maybe it's just me but is it good practice to include an end of string character in a group?
 - \d{3} What about systems where they seperate by 2?
 - `(?:[,.](\d*))` Could this be `^\2` instead of `[,.]`?

Comment: No problem, `(?=([.,](?!\d+$)| |))` you can use `\h` instead of " ", that seems a good idea. There, you need to find `nothing` because later on you use that matched group (repeated several times) for the rest of the regexp. So in order to match numbers with no separators like 123456789 you need to find (123nothing) for later on matching 456nothing and 789nothing. Also, this `(?!\d+$)` is used for treating 123,456 as a decimal number. You basically don't want to find up to 3 digits + [.,] + some numbers on the first part because if so, it will be whole number. You match them later as fractional

Comment: About your last question: you cannot replace last `[,.]` by `\2`. Because that `[.,]` is used for matching the decimal part and it must not be the same as the number separator. About systems that separate by 2: Do you mean numbers separated like this: "12.34.56.78"? Sorry, I didn't know them and it was not on your requirements. If you really need them I could study a new modification on the regexp to match them.